# How to adjust y axis distance in python plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm finding the solution to adjust the distance of y axis in plotly using python. Which parameter in plotly can help me to perform it?

This is for changing the tick value and tick name but I do not know how to disable auto-margin for y axis and change their distance.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

This is the sample data

```
Time = {'trace1':[0.02123456,0.14564545,0.01456445,0.914564],
   'trace2':[0.14564564,0.00245646,0.0045646,0.0345646],
   'dd':['2019-09-09','2019-09-10','2019-09-11','2019-09-12']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Time,columns=['trace1','trace2','dd'])
```

create trace 1

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(x = df.dd,
                y = df.trace1,
                mode = "lines",
                name = "trace1",
                marker = dict(color = 'rgba(42, 140, 239, 1)')
)
```

create trace 2

```
trace2 = go.Scatter(x = df.dd,
               y = df.trace2,
               mode = "lines",
               name = "trace2",
               marker = dict(color = 'rgba(239, 140, 42, 1)'))
```

This is the code for create graph

```
data = [trace1,trace2]


layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Estimated Time',

    xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(
    tickformat = '%Y-%m-%d',
    tickangle = 45),

    yaxis = go.layout.YAxis(range = [0.001,1],
                        autorange = False,
                        title = "Seconds",
                        tickvals = [0.0010,0.0100,0.1000,1.0000],
                       ticktext= ["0.0010","0.0100","0.1000","1.0000"]
                       ),

legend = dict(orientation="h",x=0.4,y = -0.2)
)

fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)

iplot(fig)
```

Current result:

[image]

Expected result (no overlap):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case it looks like you want to make a logarithmic scale, so I'd recommend adding `type='log'` to the arguments of `go.Layout.Yaxis()`.